# Using Squid cache_peer for performance in an Apache cluster

Tags: apache-2.2, squid, reverse-proxy

I have 3 nodes in a web server cluster. Each node is running Squid on the LAN interface and Apache on the localhost interface. Squid caches properly for each server individually, but I don't believe I setup cache peers correctly.

```
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=Server1
cache_peer Server2 sibling 80 3130 proxy-only
cache_peer Server3 sibling 80 3130 proxy-only
cache_peer_access Server1 allow MYDOMAIN
```

Each server has similar cache_peer settings except each is its own parent and uses the other two servers as siblings. My goal is to improve hit rate as much as possible, but I don't know if I'm understanding the cache peer logic correctly.

I want Squid to try to find http://www.example.com/mypage/ in it's local cache, and if it's not query the siblings until it finds it. If it can't find it, THEN it should hit Apache.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Are you getting any error message? Why do you believe your setup is not working.

Comment: I don't see anything in the access logs about hitting up a peer for a cache object. Instead, it seems like all the Squid instances are throwing their own TCP_MISS and fetching the object themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squid tries to query each peer via ICP, measures response times and then decides which parent to use. There is common problems:

- your peers doesn't respond on ICP queries and squid marks them as DEAD
- your peers doesn't support cache digest
- you are serving not cacheable content and squid always connects directly
- your acl rules doesn't allows use other peers

Answer is in your access logs. so try this and give us an example:
tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log

Answer (score 0):

So in this example, do you have squid listening to your external IP on port 80, and apache bound to localhost:80 on each server?

One thing to check is to make sure you have `icp_port 3130` if you're running squid 3.0 or above; in 2.x versions 3130 it was the default but in 3.x it's now 0 (disabled).

Comment: Correct. Each web server has Squid listening on the LAN interface on port 80, and Apache is bound to localhost on port 80. I'm using the Debian Lenny package (2.7).